# How to set data to a service function in AngularJS ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to persist information inside a service so that I can access the data across controllers.  Here is what I tried :

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

    <div  ng-controller="ControllerOne as one">
        <h2>ControllerOne:</h2>
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="emp in EmployeeInfo">
      <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
       <td>{{emp.hireDate}}</td>
       <td><a class="btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="storeIds({{emp.idUser}})" >E-Verify</a></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
        Change testService.loginName: <input type='text' ng-model='one.myService.UserId'/> </br></br>
        myName: {{one.myService.UserId}}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div ng-controller="ControllerTwo as two">
        <h2>ControllerTwo:</h2>
        myName: {{two.myService.UserId}}
    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
app.service('testService', function(){
    this.UserId= uId;
});

app.controller('ControllerOne', function($scope, testService){
    $scope.storeIds = function (userid) {
      // HERE I want to call the testService and set the value.  
    }
    this.myService = testService;
});

app.controller('ControllerTwo', function($scope, testService){
    this.myService = testService;
});
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your problem into jsfiddle?

Comment: All I want is to caputure emp.idUser while I am in ControllerOne and make it available in controllerTwo

Comment: The reason I ask for jsfiddle because you might not be aware of typos and trivial mistakes. 
You can try changing `ng-click="storeIds({{emp.idUser}})` to `ng-click="storeIds(emp.idUser)`

----
And in `$scope.storeIds` function, just assign the data to the service.
    `$scope.storeIds = function (userid) {
      testService.UserId = userid;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking into using $rootScope?

```
app.controller('ControllerOne', function($scope, rootScope, testService){
$scope.storeIds = function (userid) {


  // HERE I want to call the testService and set the value.  
}
$rootScope.myService = userid;
});

app.controller('ControllerTwo', function($scope, ,rootScope, testService){
//rootScope.myService will now equal whatever the userid was in the other controller. 
//I skipped using the service
```

});